# Accessing a specific XML element using xpath in PHP 7.x

Tags: php, xml, xpath, simplexml

Ok so I have some XML data.

```
$mydata = <<<XML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE fmresultset PUBLIC "-//FMI//DTD fmresultset//EN" "https://HIDDEN:443/fmi/xml/fmresultset.dtd">
<fmresultset xmlns="http://www.filemaker.com/xml/fmresultset" version="1.0">    
    <resultset count="1" fetch-size="1">
        <record mod-id="27" record-id="754">
            <field name="a_Constant_c">
                <data>1</data>
            </field>
            <field name="a_Sch_ID_pk">
                <data>100060</data>
            </field>
            <field name="a_SchoolHead_pk">
                <data>100060_1</data>
            </field>
            <field name="b___Data_____________">
                <data/>
            </field>
            <field name="b_1Name_School_Code_t">
                <data>PJA</data>
            </field>
            <field name="b_1Name_School_t">
                <data>Palmetto</data>
            </field>
            <field name="b_1Name_SchoolHead_t">
                <data>John Doe</data>
            </field>
            <field name="b_Ad_Address1_t">
                <data/>
            </field>
            <field name="b_Ad_Address2_t">
                <data>123 Main St.</data>           
        </record>
    </resultset>
</fmresultset>
XML;
```

Now what I want to do is basically be able to read the value of the data from a specific field and assign it to a variable.

So far I have something like this...

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($mydata);
```

Now I want to be able to assign let's say the data in the field name b_1Name_School_Code_t (which is PJA)

So I think it should be something like this

```
$school = $xml->resultset->record->field->data;
echo "School Name: ".$school;
```

Then I would like to see on the screen

```
School Name: PJA
```

So what I am missing to be able to make this happen?

Comment: Here is no Xpath call in your code. Are you looking for `SimpleXMLElement::xpath()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only getting to the first `field` element in your example, which is why you get `1`. Instead, loop through all the `field` elements, and stop when you get to the one you need:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($mydata);
$fields = $xml->resultset->record->field;
foreach ($fields as $field) {
    if ((string) $field->attributes()->name === "b_1Name_School_Code_t") {
        echo "School name: ".$field->data; // School name: PJA
        break;
    }
}
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/GOCqf)

I use [`SimpleXMLElement::attributes()`](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.attributes.php) to get the `name` attribute of the element (note the cast to `string`, otherwise you get an `SimpleXMLElement`)

However, it would make more sense to use XPath to go directly to the element you're after:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($mydata);
$xml->registerXPathNamespace("fmresultset", "http://www.filemaker.com/xml/fmresultset");
$node = $xml->xpath("//fmresultset:resultset/fmresultset:record/fmresultset:field[@name='b_1Name_School_Code_t']");
var_dump($node[0]->data); // PJA
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/PFeOI)

*Notice the namespace registration and the accessing of the first element, since [`xpath()`](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php) returns an array of `SimpleXMLElement`s*

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.

Comment: Awesome! Which way did you end up using?

Comment: I'm not sure but I thnk I will use the first one. Reason being is this is just one school. I used only one school in my example here but in the real XML it is a call to a FM database and it returns lots of schools so there will be more than one <record> element in the <resultset> so I think looping over it might work best.